# Ruby metaclasses class hierarchy

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

[This post](http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model) about metaclasses and their place in Ruby’s object model has a class hierarchy diagram. In it, `Class:Class` (`Class`’s singleton class) is an instance of itself, but I think it should be an instance of `Class`. Put it another way, if we have the object `class_singletonclass` as follows:

```
class_singletonclass = Class.singleton_class
# => #<Class:Class>
```

where is its internal class pointer `klass` pointing to? Where is `klass` pointing to in the case of `Class`, assuming that we defined a class method (singleton method) for `Class`?

I realise that `Class` has already class methods defined. I guess that `Class` is special and has its own C implementation in MRI, so that adding class methods would create a proper metaclass. Is this assumption wrong?

I found the following in `class.c` in MRI:

```
/*!
 * A utility function that wraps class_alloc.
 *
 * allocates a class and initializes safely.
 * \param super     a class from which the new class derives.
 * \return          a class object.
 * \pre  \a super must be a class.
 * \post the metaclass of the new class is Class.
 */
VALUE
rb_class_boot(VALUE super)
{
    VALUE klass = class_alloc(T_CLASS, rb_cClass);

    RCLASS_SET_SUPER(klass, super);
    RCLASS_M_TBL(klass) = st_init_numtable();

    OBJ_INFECT(klass, super);
    return (VALUE)klass;
}
```

The line `\post the metaclass of the new class is Class.` suggests that `Class`’s  metaclass is, indeed, `Class` and this applies to all metaclasses.

Comment: It may be worth making your own version of the diagram. My understanding of your question is "The looped-back dotted line (representing *instance of*) on meta-class `<Class>` (in blue) should not in fact be looped to itself, but should point to the regular `Class` (in green), am I right?" - I barely understand this, which doesn't help, but I am currently having some trouble navigating your question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to say. Sorry if my wording is too confusing.

Comment: It is trying to untangle the many distinctions of the word "class" that is confusing. I think it takes Herculean effort to write about this subject clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve adapted the `inheritance` extension from the post linked above to Ruby 2.0:

**inheritance.c**

```
#include "ruby.h"

VALUE real_super(VALUE self)
{
  return RCLASS_SUPER(RBASIC(self)->klass);
}

VALUE real_klass(VALUE self)
{
  return RBASIC(self)->klass;
}

void Init_inheritance()
{
  rb_define_method(rb_cClass,"real_super",real_super,0);
  rb_define_method(rb_cClass,"real_klass",real_klass,0);
}
```

**test.rb**

```
require_relative 'inheritance'

puts "Object real class: #{Object.real_klass}"
puts "Object real superclass: #{Object.real_super}"

puts "Class real class: #{Class.real_klass}"
puts "Class real superclass: #{Class.real_super}"

puts "Class metaclass real class: #{Class.singleton_class.real_klass}"
puts "Class metaclass real superclass: #{Class.singleton_class.real_super}"

puts "Object metaclass real class: #{Object.singleton_class.real_klass}"
puts "Object metaclass real superclass: #{Object.singleton_class.real_super}"

puts "An object singleton class real class: #{Object.new.singleton_class.real_klass}"
puts "An object singleton class real superclass: #{Object.new.singleton_class.real_super}"
```

The output being:

```
Object real class: #<Class:Object>
Object real superclass: #<Class:BasicObject>
Class real class: #<Class:Class>
Class real superclass: #<Class:Module>
Class metaclass real class: #<Class:#<Class:Class>>
Class metaclass real superclass: #<Class:#<Class:Module>>
Object metaclass real class: #<Class:#<Class:Object>>
Object metaclass real superclass: #<Class:#<Class:BasicObject>>
An object singleton class real class: #<Class:Object>
An object singleton class real superclass: #<Class:BasicObject>
```

So that in the case of metaclasses, `klass` points to the metaclass itself (and that part of the diagram is correct, but that points at some inconsistencies in  and ).

Comment: My answer was typed in a bit of a hurry, so that I just wanted to clarify matters a bit.
The part of the diagram that is correct is the one which states that `Class:Class` is an instance of itself, but as that applies to all metaclasses (i.e. a metaclass is an instance of itself) the part of the diagram about `Class:Object` and `Class:Module` is incorrect, at least for Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Additonally, the comments in `class.c` then should be interpreted as Ruby semantics but not implementation. From Ruby’s standpoint metaclasses are anonymous classes that are traversed through in the class hierarchy.